# Command line argument with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to execute below python script. But getting below issue after execution.

**Code**

```
 #!/usr/bin/python



def Student(Student_Id):


  msg = Student_Id + "." + 

  return msg
```

**Error**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>Test.py 2asd
```

After an investigation found that argument which I am passing through the command line is considered as Null.

Comment: you could `import sys` in your script and the first item in the comman line can be read in script as 'a = sys.argv[1]', where a is basically 2asd when read using the command `>>python Test.py 2asd`

Answer (score -1):

You need to call like

```
Test.py -n 2asd
```

Comment: There's no such requirement?

Calling "Test.py 2asd" will put "2asd" in sys.argv[1].

Comment: The original question had optparse with an add_argument -n and the OP was calling Test.py 2asd without doing -n. Hence, the answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52152122/revisions